# How do we continue at the inductive step?

Tags: permutations, induction, permutation-cycles

Let $\pi\in \text{Sym}(n)$. Then it is of the form $\pi=\pi_1\circ \pi_2\circ \ldots \circ \pi_m$, with $m\leq n$.

We have that $\pi_i$ has maximum length $n$.

We suppose that the $\pi_i$'s are disjoint cycles.

We want to show that $(\pi_1\circ \pi_2\circ \ldots \circ \pi_m)^x= \pi_1^x\circ \pi_2^x\circ \ldots \circ \pi_m^x$ using induction. The induction is on $m$, right?

We have the following:

Base Case : For $m=1$ we have that $\pi=\pi_1$ and so $\pi^x=\pi_1^x$, which is true.

Inductive Hypothesis : We suppose that it holds for $m=k$, i.e. it holds that $(\pi_1\circ \pi_2\circ \ldots \circ \pi_k)^x= \pi_1^x\circ \pi_2^x\circ \ldots \circ \pi_k^x$.

Inductive Step : We want to show that it holds for $m=k+1$. How can we use the inductive hypothesis at $(\pi_1\circ \pi_2\circ \ldots \circ \pi_k\circ \pi_{k+1})^x$ ?

Comment: I don't know that induction is the most natural way to go here (although I'm sure any general argument has some form of induction hidden away in three dots somewhere). Just use that they are disjoint cycles, and you should be golden.